# Time-based WFR Not Working

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I created:

1. **date/time custom field** - this will copy the last modified date of cases via the WFRs below if the edit is made via case comment and email only

a. **WFR1 Case Comment Object**- (Case: Status NOT EQUAL TO Closed) AND (Case Comment: Created Date EQUALS TODAY)
Field to Update: **date/time custom field** 
Formula Value : NOW ()

b. **WF2 Email Message Object** - (Case: Status NOT EQUAL TO Closed) AND (Email Message: Message Date EQUALS TODAY) AND (Email Message: Status EQUALS New,Read,Replied,Sent)
Field to Update: **date/time custom field** 
Formula Value : NOW ()

2. **number formula field** - serve as a counter which shows the number of days since the case was last modified
3. **Time Based WF** - this will update the case status to closed if "**number formula field**" is greater than 1

(Case: Status NOT EQUAL TO Closed) AND 
(Case: Case Owner NOT EQUAL TO Support Queue) AND
(Case: **number formula field** GREATER THAN 1)

Time Dependent WF Action : Field Update
1 Day After Rule Trigger Date
Field to Update: Case: Status
New Field Value: Closed

Unfortunately I can't make it work.

Comment: Tips:  (1) Selectively reduce the problem by testing out ea WFR one at a time to verify component elements to overall use case; (2) Use debug log to see how ea wfr evaluates incoming filters vs object values; (3) reformat the above to make it more readable - including, perhaps a sequence diagram showing the expected order of events

Comment: Setup a debug log and attempt to trigger the workflow.  You should see that it is either being triggered or not.  It sounds like you're just not having your Workflow Rule Triggered... not that it is an issue with the time-based part.

Comment: Formula fields DO NOT update over time to trigger time based wfr. Your best bet would be setting a date field on the last edit and have the war to fire 24 hrs after that date/time. Every edit will increment the date field so the WFR will be reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WFR fire when conditions are met at the time a record is saved on creation or update. That holds true for time based WFR, only a timer starts running to execute the actions at a later moment.

Your formula field in the scenario you describe is < 1 at the time your record is saved, so your WFR does not fire.

If I understand your use case correctly you want to close cases automatically after a day without any edits. You would have to create a time dependent WFR then that checks one day later if any changes to the record are made, and if this is not the case, change the status to closed